# Download speed on 5.8Ghz WiFi much slower than 2.4Ghz on Ubuntu 18.04, despite higher bit rate

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking

I have a new machine with an [Asus ROG STRIX H370I](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-H370-I-GAMING/) main board, with an Intel 2x2 802.11ac wi-fi with MU-MIMO support. My cable connection speed is around 800-900 Mbps (both upstream and downstream), and my wireless speed, on the 5.8Ghz network, is around 200Mbps (both upstream and downstream) on my iPhone 6 and Macbook Air 2011.

When it comes to my Ubuntu machine though, download speed on 5.8Ghz is painfully slow (around 6Mbps) while upload speed is around 200Mbps. If I switch to a 2.4Ghz, I get around 60 Mbps download and 160 Mbps upload speed.

I see a similar behavior on my other network as well, so I suspect it should be a driver issue. But I installed the [latest wi-fi driver](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.618819.0.tgz) to no avail. Moreover, 5Ghz does give me higher bit rate (according to iwconfig), but for some reason it's not translated to higher download speed.

Here is the results of some commands.

```
~ iwconfig  enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Casal-5G"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.58 GHz  Access Point: 40:A5:EF:56:E8:02   
          Bit Rate=866.7 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-32 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:91   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

 ~ curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/master/speedtest.py | python - Retrieving speedtest.net configuration... Testing from Cogent Communications (38.26.29.60)... Retrieving speedtest.net server list... Selecting best server based on ping... Hosted by Rogers (Toronto, ON) [2.33 km]: 80.114 ms Testing download speed................................................................................ Download: 9.81 Mbit/s Testing upload speed................................................................................................ Upload: 217.09 Mbit/s

 ~ sudo lshw -c network
   *-network:0               
         description: Wireless interface
              product: Intel Corporation
              vendor: Intel Corporation
              physical id: 14.3
              bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
              logical name: wlo1
              version: 10
              serial: 00:1c:bf:fc:4c:8e
              width: 64 bits
              clock: 33MHz
              capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
              configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-23-generic firmware=34.0.0 ip=192.168.1.13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
              resources: irq:16 memory:a1234000-a1237fff
         *-network
         description: Ethernet interface
              product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
              vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
              physical id: 0
              bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
              logical name: enp2s0
              version: 15
              serial: 9c:5c:8e:bc:89:66
              size: 10Mbit/s
              capacity: 1Gbit/s
              width: 64 bits
              clock: 33MHz
              capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
              configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
              resources: irq:123 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a1104000-a1104fff memory:a1100000-a1103fff
         *-network:1
         description: Ethernet interface
              product: Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V
              vendor: Intel Corporation
              physical id: 1f.6
              bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
              logical name: eno1
              version: 10
              serial: 9c:5c:8e:bb:c6:16
              capacity: 1Gbit/s
              width: 32 bits
              clock: 33MHz
              capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
              configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.4-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
              resources: irq:124 memory:a1200000-a121ffff
```

Comment: You should avoid using 5G as a shortcut for 5Ghz, because a 5G network is a next-generation mobile data network and not what you’re trying to ask about.

Comment: Like most WiFi performance issues, this question is pretty vague and giving a definitive answer is difficult without significantly more technical information. That said, in general the most common first step in improving WiFi speeds on Intel chipsets in Linux is to disable Power Management, have you tried that?

Comment: @acejavelin Please elaborate what other technical information should I provide. And yes, I have turned off the Power Management.

Comment: @MikeScott it's GHz, not Ghz, because the unit symbol is Hz

Comment: @phuclv Quite right, I stand corrected.

Comment: @MikeScott Thanks for the edit. Though IMHO, 5G wifi is a common term, and distinct enough to not be confused with the mobile network tech.

Comment: (1) Troubleshooting: The article [Speed Up Slow WiFi Connection In Ubuntu Linux](https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/) has some manipulations that might help. (2) Driver problems : try a live Linux distro that is not based on debian/ubuntu. (3) Hardware : try another wifi adapter.

Comment: Possibly related: [TCP small queues](https://lwn.net/Articles/757643/) WLAN performance impact. I'd try to recompile the kernel with this patch, and see if it helps.

Comment: Most WiFi adapters' firmware is commercial and not free to use. In order to be in track with their policy, Linux use OSS drivers, which are not in the same quality and problems with them are widely-known and common in the Linux community. Unless you get lucky enough to find a WiFi card which will work flawlessly with those OSS drivers on Linux, I doubt the issue would be fixable, as it most likely **is** a driver-related issue, especially when you're using 5GHz, which is not well compatible with OSS drivers.

Comment: 802.11n speed requires WPA2 security with AES encryption. Are these your settings? And please also remark on my previous comment.

Comment: @harrymc Yes, as explained in the question, other devices work properly on this network, so the issue cannot be with the router settings. And yes, I have gone through that link. It doesn't have any solution for this specific problem. And I cannot use another distro or wifi adapter.

Comment: I think that the only conclusion is that Ubuntu does not have the right driver for your network adapter. Could you let us know its exact  model number which should look like "AC model-number".

Comment: It is not enough that the other devices work properly under the same network. It is also needed from the same point and at the same time (to avoid local interferences or weakness of the filed). BTW to exclude hardware problem you should check the error rates too.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only conclusion is that Ubuntu does not have the right driver for your network adapter.

According to information by
[Tom's Hardware](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/intel-b360-h370-h310-chipsets,36813.html),
your network adapter is the Intel Wireless-AC 9560.

The article
[Linux* Support for Intel® Wireless Adapters](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html)
from 20-Dec-2017, lists the current driver as
[iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.618819.0.tgz](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.618819.0.tgz)
and the contents are in fact dated from December 2017.

Check if this driver is more recent than yours.
If it is, the installation method listed is :

> 1. Copy the files into the distribution-specific firmware directory, /lib/firmware.
> 2. If the directory does not work, consult your distribution documentation.
> 3. If you configure the kernel yourself, make sure firmware loading is enabled.

If this replaces some files, better backup the current files before starting.

If your problem is not fixed, raise the problem in the appropriate
forums, or get an external network adapter that has better support
by Ubuntu.

Comment: As stated in the question, I had already installed the latest version of the driver to no avail. I had asked the same question on askubuntu as well. Any pointer to a more appropriate forum is appreciated.

Comment: There are also the [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/) and the [Intel Support Communities](https://communities.intel.com/community/tech).